# Why doesn't Windows 7 app see virtualized registry value on first run?

Tags: windows-7, registry

I have written a C# program which first reads and then writes a value from/to HKLM\Software\MyApp.  It is an x86 app with no manifest, and I am running as a non-administrator, on Windows 7, x86, so I expect it to actually read from and write to the corresponding virtualized registry location (HKCU\Software\Classes\VirtualStore\Machine\Software\MyApp.)

Before running my app, I have placed, by hand, through regedit, one value in the virtualized location, and a different value in the HKLM location.

The first time I run my app, it reads the HKLM value, and does not see the virtualized value.  When it writes, though, it writes to the virtualized location.

However, on subsequent runs (after the first write to the virtualized location) the application does read the virtualized value, rather than the one in HKLM.

I am trying to figure out what changes between the first and subsequent runs that would cause a discrepancy in where it is reading from.  It is not the virtual flags on HKLM\Software\MyApp -- they are all clear both before and after the first run.

I have repeated this on several different user accounts.  (And, FWIW, I have also seen QuickTime behave the same way, which is actually the reason I am playing around with this.)  It is worth noting that the first run of each user has the same behavior, regardless of whether a different user had already run the application on the same machine.

Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\MyApp");
        if (key != null)
        {
            String value = (string)key.GetValue("name");
            Console.WriteLine("read value " + value);
            key.Close();
        }
        else Console.WriteLine("open key for read failed");
        key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\MyApp", true);
        if (key != null)
        {
            key.SetValue("name", "programValue");
            Console.WriteLine("Wrote value programValue");
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("open key for write failed");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Before running for the first time, the following values are in the registry:

> HKLM\Software\MyApp:name = "handHKLMValue"
>   HKCU\Software\Classes\VirtualStore\Machine\Software\MyApp:name = "handVirtualValue"

The output of the first run is:

> read value handHKLMValue
>   Wrote value programValue

Looking in the registry, I can see that programValue has indeed been written to the virtualized location, overwriting handVirtualValue.  I.e., the registry now contains the following values:

> HKLM\Software\MyApp:name = "handHKLMValue"
>   HKCU\Software\Classes\VirtualStore\Machine\Software\MyApp:name = "programValue"

And, sure enough, subsequent runs have output:

> read value programValue
>   Wrote value programValue

What could have possibly changed between the first and subsequent runs, and what do I have to do (short of directly looking in the virtualized location) so that it will read handVirtualValue on the first run?